# pascal - How pass record key as a procedure parameter?

Tags: types, parameters, record, pascal, procedure

i have little issue with record + procedure in pascal. I have declared record as a Type and i want this record key as a parameter in procedure

Here is record structure & declaration:

```
person = record
  name:string[20];
  age:integer;
end;

var x:person
```

and i have this procedure, **I DO NOT KNOW WHAT INSERT IN PARAMETER**:

```
procedure out(param);
begin
  writeln(param);
end;
```

and calling procedure in main body of program:

```
x.name := 'Obama';
x.age := 35;

out(x.name);
out(x.age);
```

how to access to certain key of record and how to pass it in parameter ? thanks

Comment: Why don't you pass Person to out and then writeln name and age?

Comment: because i dont want writeln all keys in record

Comment: What do you need out for then? All you are doing is aliasing writeln? Record is just syntactic sugar, it all disappears during compilation. You can't do anything like Person['name']. If you really need out then it;s gong to have to be OutAge, OutName, OutNameAndAge etc. You are finding out why we came up with OO. :(

Comment: You can't write one procedure that will accept both a string and an integer in the same parameter. Write separate procedures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
procedure out(param:person);
begin
  writeln(param.name);
  writeln(param.age);
end;
```

Comment: It would be better, if you add some explanation or reference (e.g. to a documentation) to your answer.